# How to submit from page to redirect from.php page with 60sec waiting progress bar in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, progress-bar, form-submit

[image]
How to submit from page to redirect from.php page with 60sec waiting progress bar in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

you can manage the progress bar manually on your form.php file.

I have shared the link. Please follow the steps, [Displaying Progress Bar On Form Submission Using jQuery](https://www.formget.com/displaying-progress-bar-on-form-submission-using-jquery/)